# Vue Router issue with dynamic route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to make these routes:

```
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '/:username',
  name: 'login',
  component: Login
},
{
  path: '/dashboard',
  name: 'dashboard',
  component: Dashboard
}
```

But when I try to open /dashboard, I get Login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is important here. You can swap `/dashboard` and `/:username` position

```
[{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'dashboard',
      component: Dashboard
},
{
  path: '/:username',
  name: 'login',
  component: Login
}]
```

Comment: Oh wow. This is just works, thank you! Is this described in docs?

Comment: @ittus  Maybe you can hep me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836601/how-can-make-dynamyc-routes-on-the-vue-router

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. Router is matching the routes from first to last.
/dashboard totally matches /:username with username == 'dashboard'

You should place the login roote at the end of the array, but even better you'd prefix it to be safer (like /user/:username)